# Saying "I did X because of Y"

Tags: grammar

Is there a common way to express the reason for something *after* stating what the something is? All the ways I can think of explaining situations involve putting it before. I.e. ～から～です. I was hoping to say something along the lines of "I had this thought because ~".

Comment: There's also a construction that involves ため that can work for this. YはXためだ。

Comment: Does that sound weird? I feel like if I said I did X, then saying "YはXためだ" sounds weird or something. It doesn't?

Comment: Well, that's what they taught me... but it's saying X is the reason for Y. rather than X is the thing done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do that.  I will only introduce the patterns most often used by us native speakers.  Note that to do this in Japanese, it will basically take two separate sentences.  In informal writing, however, one could get away with combining the two into one by replacing the period after the first sentence with a comma.

1) 「A sentence.  なぜなら～～～からです。」

2）「A sentence.  ～～～からです。」

3) 「A sentence.  というのは～～～からです。」

4) 「A sentence.  ～～～という理由からです。」

To express "I had this thought because ~~.", you could say:

「XXXと思いました。（なぜなら/というのは）～～からです。」or

「XXXと思いました。 ～～という理由からです。」

Comment: It requires two sentences for putting the reason after- in English does it require two sentences for putting the reason before? I don't think it does, but maybe it's the same as how you said you could get away with putting a comma? I mean I could say, in English, My stomach was empty, so I ate the cookie. Is that the same feeling as the informal writing? Does it really sound weird to use one sentence in spoken Japanese?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is:

> X のは Y からです。

So your specific example could be naturally expressed as:

> そう思ったのは～からです。